# AVDM not opening in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have installed Eclipse and trying to setup Android Virtual Device. But when I click "Android Virtual Device Manager" option, nothing happens. Its not opening.
I tried installing plugin again, but it says plugin already installed.
what should I do?